# With Python C API, How to find the Union_Type?

Tags: python, c

I would like to create a new `Union[int,str]` type.

I would like to have access on instance `Union_Type` to create a new type like `Union[int,str]`.

The `PyType_Type` is public, so I can write

```c
(PyObject*)&PyType_Type
```

But `Union_Type` is not public, so I can't write

```c
(PyObject*)&Union_Type
```

Can I add in my C code ?

```c
PyAPI_DATA(PyTypeObject) UnionType_Type;
```

Sample of code:

```c
PyObject *newUnion=PyObject_GetItem(&UnionType_Type,
    PyTuple_Pack(2,&PyLong_Type,&PyUnicode_Type));
```

I would like to have a `PyObject*` to Union type to invoke the `__getitem__()` and create a new sub type.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? `Union` and other `typing` module types are almost entirely useless at C level. They're almost exclusively useful for type annotations, which can't be used through the C API.

Comment: If you want to provide type annotations for a C module, I believe the currently standard approach is to write a stub file.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a matter of `Union_Type` not being public. `Union_Type` doesn't *exist*. `typing.Union` is not defined through a C-level global variable; it is defined through a `class` statement in the `typing` module.

If you want to access `typing.Union` through the C API, you have to do the exact same thing you would do at Python level: [import](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html) `typing` and [access the `Union` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetAttrString) of the module object. With a few rare exceptions, this is the same process you should use to access the contents of any importable module at C level.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
PyObject* typing = PyImport_ImportModule("typing")
PyObject* unionType = PyObject_GetAttrString(typing,"Union");
PyObject* tuple = PyTuple_Pack(2,&PyLong_Type,&PyUnicode_Type)
PyObject *newUnion=PyObject_GetItem(unionType,tuple);
Py_DECREF(typing);
Py_DECREF(unionType);
Py_DECREF(unionType);
Py_DECREF(tuple);
```